# I need to make a "sign up" request from react front-end to Scala back-end api

Tags: reactjs, npm, axios

I am a new to React.js, currently is doing my university project. Basically, my Sign up api was completed and successfully, but now, how do I call an api to react front end? I have review some of the example from youtube and stackoverfloe, but I still stuck on here. Below I will describe more about my current situation:

Here is api my result I get on postman.
[image]

So I have no problem with my API.

Here is how I call my API to react frontend:

```
    handleSubmit(event){

        const {
            name,
            email,
            UserMobile,
            Password,
            confirmPassword,
            Organisation_Name,
            Address,
            description
        } = this.state;
        console.log(this.state)

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost:9000/api/users/sign-up',
            data: {
                name: name,
                email: email,
                UserMobile: UserMobile,
                Password: Password,
                confirmPassword: confirmPassword,
                Organisation_Name: Organisation_Name,
                Address: Address,
                description: description
            },
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
```

Here is some source code of :

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input 
                        type="type" 
                        name="name" 
                        placeholder="name" 
                        value={this.state.name || ''} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="email" 
                        name="email" 
                        placeholder="email" 
                        value={this.state.email} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="UserMobile" 
                        placeholder="UserMobile" 
                        value={this.state.UserMobile || ''} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="Password" 
                        name="Password" 
                        placeholder="Password" 
                        value={this.state.Password || ''} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="Password" 
                        name="confirmPassword" 
                        placeholder="confirmPassword" 
                        value={this.state.confirmPassword || ''} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="Organisation_Name" 
                        name="Organisation_Name" 
                        placeholder="Organisation_Name" 
                        value={this.state.Organisation_Name || ''} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="Address" 
                        name="Address" 
                        placeholder="Address" 
                        value={this.state.Address || ''} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <input 
                        type="description" 
                        name="description" 
                        placeholder="description" 
                        value={this.state.description || ''} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        required
                    />

                    <button type="Submit">Registration</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

package.json (in case needed)

```
  "name": "react-redux-router",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Basic skeleton codebase for React/Redux/Router applications.",
  "proxy": {
    "/connect": {
      "target": "http://localhost:9000",
      "secure": false,
      "changeOrigin": true
    }
  },
```

So is it a correct way for react to call the API? and why I cannot get the result as same as postman result? The new user are not enter to the database as well. Hopefully anyone can help me and teach me for this kind of issue.

Comment: Hi, good question & good luck in your studies. Does your axois method log anything to the console? I cannot see anything wrong at first look at your code. Would you be able to create an example through https://codesandbox.io/s/new?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-thunder-d35wz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

@P.Brew

Comment: Good new is that there does not look to be anything wrong with your logic. Axios is not even trying to make a network request so that leads me to believe that http://localhost:9000/api/users/sign-up is not recognised as a valid web address. Is it possible to either publish your API onto a server anywhere, alternatively get the IP address of the machine running localhost:9000 and call that instead. So rather than http://localhost:port you should use http://your_ip_address:port